# How to show/hide form if user is logged in Backbone, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am a beginner in JavaScript and Backbone.
Right now I am trying to show or hide an input form depending if the user is logged in.
In my TestView.js I defined user toJSON in data:{}.
Now in my HTML I have this form

```
<form class="test">
            <% if(user.isLoggedIn) { %>
                <input type="text"name="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <% } %>
```

What is the correct syntax around this input to hide the name field if the user is logged in and show it if user is not logged in?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define the form as a separate template (using underscore templates or something similar). Then in your view say something like `if (user.isLoggedIn) { this.$el.append(YOURTEMPLATE) }`

Edit: Do this to keep unnecessary stuff out of the DOM. Also, `this.$el` depends on what your `el` is of course.